# JavaScript Dictionary reversal

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Dictionary which has 5 keys `var langDict = {};`

```
IT-PL
EN
DE-FR
ZH-CH
IT-ES
```

I want the DE-FR to be in first position and EN in second position, others doesn't matter.

I am thinking to achieve this using a below recursive method but not getting the expected result.

```
for (var key in langDict) {
    if (Object.keys(langDict).length > 0) {
        langDict = filterKeys(langDict);
    }
}

function filterKeys(langDict) {
    for (var key in langDict) {
        var langDictFiltered = {};
        if (key.indexOf("DE") > -1) {
            langDictFiltered[key] = langDict[key];
            delete langDict[key];
            break;
        }
        if (key.indexOf("EN") > -1) {
            langDictFiltered[key] = langDict[key];
            delete langDict[key];
            break;
        }
    }

    return langDict;
}
```

Comment: You'd better create a new array from those keys and base your actions on it. Object properties are unordered.

Comment: two properties(DE,EN ) is a very small cost for such issue - order them manually

Comment: What environment are you running in?  ES6 [defines an order](http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) for property traversal.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?
What are you trying to do with the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects have no special order, but you could take all keys of the object ([`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) and take a custom sort with
[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a hash table for the sort order.

Later you can use the array with the sorted key for populating.

```js
var keys = ['IT - PL', 'EN', 'DE - FR', 'ZH - CH', 'IT - ES'];
keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    function value(v) {
        return { DE: 1, EN: 2 }[v.substring(0, 2)] || 10;
    }
    return value(a) - value(b);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Edit

Version with splitting the strings and getting the most top value first.

```js
var keys = ['IT-PL', 'EN', 'DE-FR', 'ZH-CH', 'IT-ES', 'EN-DE-FR-CH-PL'];
keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    function value(v) {
        return v.split('-').reduce(function (r, a) {
            return Math.min(r, { DE: 1, EN: 2 }[a] || 10);
        }, 10);
    }
    return value(a) - value(b);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Keys are an OBJ not array. Obj keys are not ordered

Comment: @RhysBradbury, i have nothing other claimed.

Comment: In this value "EN-DE-FR-CH-PL", it is not returning DE as first - any idea why ? - EN-DE-FR-CH-PL is a single array - I mean it is not [EN,DE,FR]

Comment: @user3674148, plese see edit. now with splitting the string and a new value function.